Preventing iTunes on Windows 11 from connecting to an unsubscribed podcast that displays an invalid server certificate warning
Each time I run iTunes, I get this:

I think this corresponds to a podcast I listened to years ago, but I have long since unsubscribed.
I think the simplest solution is to prevent iTunes from attempting to access this server by getting rid of whatever data is causing it to try, but I don't know how to do that.
Does anybody know how I can figure out why iTunes is trying to contact this server?

Just guessing here, as I don't use iTunes on Windows, but it could be podcast information is stored in the registry... have you searched the registry for "media.goethe.de"?

Good idea, but searching the registry turned up nothing.
